# c# WPF MvvM application DataGrid not updating to the database

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I am working on a WPF application using MvvM Light. I have created a databinding for my DataGrid and when I edit something there it does not update to the database and I am not sure where I went wrong.

This is my View code:

```
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NinjaApp_V2.Views"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:NinjaApp_V2.ViewModel" xmlns:NinjaApp_V2="clr-namespace:NinjaApp_V2" x:Name="NinjaCRUDWindow" x:Class="NinjaApp_V2.Views.NinjaCRUD"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="NinjaCRUD" Height="300" Width="300">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="ninjaViewSource" d:DesignSource="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type NinjaApp_V2:ninja}, CreateList=True}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <Binding Path="AddNinja" Source="{StaticResource Locator}"/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}}" Margin="0,10,3.6,0.4">
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGridNinjas" ItemsSource="{Binding Ninjas.Ninjas}">
        <DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
            <BindingGroup/>
        </DataGrid.ItemBindingGroup>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=AddWindow}" Margin="0,180,211,0">Save</Button>
</Grid>
```

The .cs of that view is completly empty as I have seen in multiple examples.

AddNinjaVM contains the SaveCommand and looks like this:

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using NinjaApp_V2.Views;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace NinjaApp_V2.ViewModel
{
    public class AddNinjaVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        public NinjaVM Ninja { get; set; }

        public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

        private NinjaListVM _ninjas;

        public AddNinjaVM(NinjaListVM ninjas)
        {
            _ninjas = ninjas;
            Ninja = new NinjaVM();
            SaveCommand = new RelayCommand<NinjaCRUD>(Save);
        }

        private void Save(NinjaCRUD obj)
        {
            using (var context = new NinjaApp_DatabaseEntities())
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            _ninjas.Ninjas.Add(Ninja);
            obj.Hide();
        }
    }
}
```

I have followed a working example from school for this. This is a part I have been stuck on for the second day now and I just do not get why it is not working in my application. Could someone perhaps help me out?

Comment: You're saving the context changes _before_ adding your ninja.  Should that not be the other way around?  (your context has to track the changes prior to be Saved, and with this code you have your context only long enough to save it - but not to add or update any entities within)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. swapped it around but it did not make any difference - thanks alot for trying to help out tho!

Comment: No problem.  Could be a WPF binding issue as well (they're notoriously difficult to get a handle on and debug).  Have you stepped through the code when the command is clicked to verify that the object in the VM has the correct values prior to being saved by EF?  That will tell you if the issue is on the WPF side or on the EF/DB side.

Comment: The datagrid does show the data from the database so we used this to validate that the EF is actually  working  correctly, only writing back to the database or freshing  the data in the datagrid does not work. If I update the database while the application is opened pressing the save button does not load the new changes into the datagrid.

Comment: Yes, but it's a two way street - one way binding tends to be easier to set up, so good that this end is working well, but you'll want to step through the code as much as possible in debug mode for the other end of things to narrow down _where_ the problem is.  Debugging is an art: first thing is to narrow down as much as possible to pinpoint where things go from good to bad.  Could be in the WPF binding, could be in the DB, could be in entity mappings somewhere between, etc.  Just keep in mind that two way binding doesn't mean that if the read end is set up, the write end automatically is also

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void Save(NinjaCRUD obj)
        {
            using (var context = new NinjaApp_DatabaseEntities())
            {
                **context.<DBtable>.Add(obj);**
                context.SaveChanges(); <---- This is where it is wrong.
            }

            _ninjas.Ninjas.Add(Ninja);  
            obj.Hide();
        }
```

You need to add the object to the context.Ninjas collection first and then call context.SaveChanges.

## Entity Framework Concepts

In Entity Framework - assume DbContext (NinjaApp_DatabaseEntities in your code) to be the Database. All tables in the actual database will appear as List (Classes called Entities) in this DbContext.

when you have to add a record to a table, you create a row which must have a value for each column in that table and then its inserted. Similarily, in entity framework, when you have to add a new record to table, you got to create an object of the Entities Type.

From you example & comments - I visualize that the Table name is "ninjas" - Hence you see context.ninjas

Next you want to add a record to this table "ninjas" - which means the object that you can add to it must also be of type of "ninjas" class.

Since you have the code, you must the Actual Type of Class representing the table and you must create a new object of it - assign values and then Add it to the context.ninjas.Add() and finally call context.SaveChanges();

Refer: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework4.3/add-entity-using-dbcontext.aspx

```
  //create DBContext object
        using (var dbCtx = new SchoolDBEntities())
        {
            //Add Student object into Students DBset
            dbCtx.Students.Add(newStudent);

            // call SaveChanges method to save student into database
            dbCtx.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not exactly sure how that would work I keep getting errors on <DBtable> and on NinjaCRUD it wants a object instead of a type

Comment: :) when I wrote <DBTable> - I mean.. the actual table/Entity name in your Entity Framework context. And the actual object of the Entity type. type context. and you will see a auto-suggest (intellisense) popup - scroll through that list to locate the table/Entity.

Comment: Yeah the first thing I actually did was replacing DBtable with context.ninjas because it's the table it' s about but it' s giving the error identifier expected. And when I change it to context.ninjas.Add(obj); I get ```cannot convert from NinjaApp_V2.Views.NinjaCRUD to NinjaApp_V2.ninja - also I am not copying any work the example is just a tiny piece of the full scope of the project. But in multiple places in the application we'll have to use datagrids to show and update information.